# how to live stream data from a mongodb which get updated frequently without refreshing the page in nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket

```
app.post('/databykey', function(req, res) {
  var api = req.body.api;
  console.log(api);
  push.getdata(api, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      var sample = [];
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        sample[i] = data[i].id
      }
      console.log(sample);
      res.render('data', {
        'data': sample
      });
    }
  })
})
```

This is my source code. I am fetching the data from the mongodb which get updated frequently.How do i render the updated data to the front end without refreshing the browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of frameworks for the front end job and each has a method for this. Simply you can use jQuery something like this by sending ajax every 2sec for example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function loaddata()
{
  $.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'server address/databykey',
  data: {
   api: 'some data'
  },
  success: function (response) {
   $( '#display_info' ).html(response);
  }
  });
 }
setInterval(loaddata, 2000);
})();

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="display_info" >
</div>

</body>
</html>
```